# Reading input in php from terminal

Tags: php

I want to read the following input in php which is entered in termial

```
3
5  
1 4 0 2 5  
2 0 5 1 4  
4  
1 1 7 2
1 13 2 1 
3
3 1 7
2 5 4
```

Where:

- The first line of input consists of an integer `T` which is the number
  of test cases.
- The first line of each test case contains an integer n which
  indicates the size of both arrays.
- The second and third line of each test case contains n space
  separated integers which are the elements of the first and second
  arrays respectively.

I am new to PHP, can anybody explain me the code logic of reading the input?

I don't want to store the input in a file and read it from there.

Any help would be appreciable, Thank you.

Comment: You may want to check the [Input/output streams](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php) chapter. See also [Reading line by line from STDIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968244/reading-line-by-line-from-stdin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function read_from_console ($prompt = '') {
    if ( function_exists('readline') ) { 
        $line = trim(readline($prompt));
        if (!empty($line)) {
            readline_add_history($line);
        }
    } else {
        echo $prompt;
        $line = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    }
    return $line;
}

$values = preg_split('/\s+/', trim(read_from_console()));
```

Comment: What is $prompt?

Comment: The text you want to show to the user as indication of what s/he has to enter. It can be an empty string. I'm going to edit...

Comment: It is working for reading lines, but how can i store the space seperated values in a line as an array?

Comment: I edited the answer. Use `explode()` or, better, `preg_split()`. `explode` splits by a string, so if you split by a single space `' '` and you have several spaces between two values you will get empty items. `preg_split` splits by a regular string, which is more complicated but much more powerful. In this case, we split by any succession of one or more whitespace characters (space or tab in this case).

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the input passed to the script via terminal, you can use the [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) variable.

For example, if you write in the terminal:

```
php -q /path/script.php one two three
```

The `var_dump($argv);` command will show:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "script.php"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "one"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "two"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "three"
}
```

So, to get the first you can simple write:

```
$first = $argv[1]; // it will be one
```

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure he intends to provide data in standard input, not as command-line parameters.

Answer (score -2):

echo 'Do you want Refresh! Go back [CTR+C or `press any key`]'
.PHP_EOL
.'Generating for new token [Y/N] ';

flush(); if ( trim( fgets( STDIN ) ) !== 'y' ) exit;