# How to add instruction on input in PHP

Tags: php, python

In Python, you can add instruction on user input like this;

```
foo = input('Enter a number:')
```

Is there any way to do the same thing in PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading line by line from STDIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968244/reading-line-by-line-from-stdin)

Answer (score 4):

The PHP `readline()` function does this:

```
<?php
$foo = readline('Enter a number:');
echo $foo;
?>
```

Read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php).