# read multiple lines using STDIN in PHP

Tags: php

I have encountered a problem that I need to solve using PHP.

I have a multiline input that looks like this:

```
a,b,c,d
a=10 tools
b=50 subtools
c=80 othertools
```

I want to read input using stdin but I'm only able to read the first line.
using `fscanf(STDIN, "%s\n", $name);`

How do I read the multiple input lines and save them to a list?  I want to use a comma as separator for first-line and space as a separator for the rest.

Comment: Have you tried using more than 1 `fscanf` calls?

Comment: Yes I have, doesn't work. If i user fscanf second time using another variable, only the first element is read. ie, a

Comment: Something like - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968244/reading-line-by-line-from-stdin

Comment: 1. Show your code. 2. `fscanf()` is going to need a more robust pattern than just `%s`. 3. If you just want the lines then just use `fgets()`.

Comment: And there will only ever be 4 lines?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fgets` you can do

```
$c = 0;
do {
    $f = fgets(STDIN);
    echo "line: $f";
    if ( $c == 0) {
        echo 'its a a,b,c,d type line' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'its a a=10 tools' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $c++;
   
} while ($c < 5);
echo 'END';
```

Or

```
$c = 0;
while ($f = fgets(STDIN) !== FALSE and $c<4) {
    echo "line: $f";
    if ( $c == 0) {
        echo 'its a a,b,c,d type line' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'its a a=10 tools' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $c++;   
}
echo 'END';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many built-in way, but the shortest and strongest way to handle all cases, huge stream length, multi-lines or not, is `stream_get_contents()`

```
var_dump(stream_get_contents(STDIN));
exit;
```